# Determine start and end of street, based on (latitude, longitude) points

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

Let's assume I have many (latitude, longitude) points, and all of them are on *one* street. However, I have no information about house numbers.

Is there any way to deduce which two points correspond to the "first" and "last" point of this street respectively? Keep in mind that a street could be straight, curved, or almost any shape really.

**What I want to do is find a way to split a street into 30-meter segments.** If I'm not mistaken, there's no way to sort/rank the (latitude, longitude) points, even in the context of one street.

Just one thing: I have too many points to use the Google Maps API (many streets); instead, I'm using a local installation of Nominatim (OpenStreetMap). Please either suggest something that can be done with Nominatim or a general algorithm.